# How to upload the video file in salesforce

Tags: salesforce1-app, sandbox

I want to upload the video file in salesforce, could you please anyone , how to upload the video file and mean while which format video is supported in salesforce

Answer (score 1):

Video would be stored in salesforce as an Attachment, static resources or document. And file format won't matter as its basically a blob.

It's the responsibility of browser to play video, if browser supports it will play . You can view such video in an vf page using below code.

```
 <video width="75%" controls="controls">
       <source src="{!URLFOR($Resource.Video)}"       type="video/mp4" />        
       Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
```